# Does SparkSQL support subquery?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, subquery, apache-spark-sql

I am running this query in Spark shell but it gives me error,

```
sqlContext.sql(
 "select sal from samplecsv where sal < (select MAX(sal) from samplecsv)"
).collect().foreach(println)
```

error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.47] failure: ``)'' expected but identifier MAX found
>
> select sal from samplecsv where sal < (select MAX(sal) from samplecsv)
>                                                 ^
>       at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
>   Can anybody explan me,thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Planned features**:

- [SPARK-23945](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23945) (Column.isin() should accept a single-column DataFrame as input).
- [SPARK-18455](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18455) (General support for correlated subquery processing).

**Spark 2.0+**

Spark SQL should support both correlated and uncorrelated subqueries. See [`SubquerySuite`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/df89f1d43d4eaa1dd8a439a8e48bca16b67d5b48/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SubquerySuite.scala) for details. Some examples include:

```
select * from l where exists (select * from r where l.a = r.c)
select * from l where not exists (select * from r where l.a = r.c)

select * from l where l.a in (select c from r)
select * from l where a not in (select c from r)
```

Unfortunately as for now (Spark 2.0) it is impossible to express the same logic using `DataFrame` DSL.

**Spark < 2.0**

Spark supports subqueries in the `FROM` clause (same as Hive <= 0.12).

```
SELECT col FROM (SELECT *  FROM t1 WHERE bar) t2
```

It simply doesn't support subqueries in the `WHERE` clause.Generally speaking arbitrary subqueries (in particular correlated subqueries) couldn't be expressed using Spark without promoting to Cartesian join.

Since subquery performance is usually a significant issue in a typical relational system and every subquery can be expressed using `JOIN` there is no loss-of-function here.

Answer (score 0):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4226

There is a pull request to implement that feature .. my guess it might land in Spark 2.0.