# Implementing a Spark SQL UserDefinedAggregateFunction that performs multiple passes over a column

Tags: apache-spark, aggregate-functions, apache-spark-sql

I've been experimenting with the `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` class to write aggregate functions for use in Spark SQL.

It works well for implementing *single pass* operations like `sum()`, `avg()` etc., but is there a trick you can use to perform multiple passes over a column?

For example, Calculating variance using the *naive* approach. i.e. With a first pass calculating the column mean and then a second pass that uses this value to calculate the variance. I know that there are single pass algorithms for doing this that give good approximations (as in fact implemented by Spark). I was just using this as an example of a two-pass operation.

It would be nice to be able to do the following,

`spark.sql("SELECT product, MultiPassAgg(price) FROM products GROUP BY product")`

I appreciate that I can do this kind of thing using `Dataset` / `DataFrame` operations in stages etc., but I was just looking *clean* approach as illustrated in the SQL above.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately this can't be done because it's not allowed to use an aggregate function in the argument of another aggregate function. You'll need to use the inner aggregate function in a sub-query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933118/why-sparksql-doesnt-support-subquery

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected.

Comment: I believe that it's a limitation from Hive and I'm not sure that Hive allows it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, though the following suggestion could potentially use a large amount of memory if a large number of rows are involved in any given partition.

In the implementation of your UserDefinedAggregateFunction, set up the `bufferSchema` having a **StructField** that includes a **DataType** that is a collection (such as **ArrayType**) to act as an internal collection of inputs provided via `update`.

Then, in `update` you append each `input` to your collection, and in `merge` you combine all of the collections into a single collection. This allows you to have the full partition available for use in `evaluate`.

Finally, during `evaluate` you can operate across the entire collection of rows in any way you see fit.