# How to use MAX and HAVING in Spark SQL?

Tags: subquery, apache-spark-sql

I am learning SPARK (1.6.1) and CASSANDRA and I have been tasked with doing analysis since I know a little bit about SQL. I am getting data’s using SPARK-SQL with CASSANDRA. I am now trying to get data from a table named **connectablesTempTable** that has the following data

userhandle     threadid      connid

```
1             1          Kooky
2             1          millicent
1             1          norseman
1             2          caribou
2             1          zoology
3             1          polypropylene
3             1          cyanided
3             2          eluted
1             2          insurrectionising
1             1          orontes
2             3          perpetualness
2             2          aphaeretic
2             1          bloodthirstiness
3             2          cingulectomy
3             3          unlimed
3             2          unprison
1             1          hereat
2             1          humidify
```

From the above thread I need to query for “**For every userhandle find out the threadid that has the maximum of connid**”. The following is the result that I expect

userhandle  threadid    maxcount

```
1         1         4
2         1         4
3         2         3
```

In SQL, I can write the following query to get the values

```
SELECT userhandle,threadid, COUNT(connid)  
FROM connectablesTempTable  
GROUP BY userhandle,threadid   
HAVING COUNT (connid)= (
    select MAX(mycount) FROM (
        SELECT userhandle,threadid, COUNT(connid) as mycount   
        FROM connectablesTempTable GROUP BY userhandle,threadid
    )
);
```

When I try to do the same in SPARk-SQL, am getting an error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.47] failure: ``)'' expected” something.

When I was browsing the internet for a solution, I noticed that the SPARK SQL doesn’t support subqueries. Is there a way for me to get the answer for the above query?

Thanks,
Jollyguy

Comment: In 1.6 spark support sub queries only in FROM clause , you may take a look at similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933118/why-sparksql-doesnt-support-subquery

Comment: firstly, i created a table that has userhandle,threadid,count(connid) and from that table using the query **"select distinct a1.userhandle,a1.threadid, a1.num from table1 a1 left join table1 a2 on a1.userhandle = a2.userhandle and a2.num > a1.num where a2.userhandle is null"** am able to get the result. There is a slight hitch, if  2 different threads has the same count(connid), it will return those 2 threadid. I would like to get the first threadid only. How to do that?