# What does "Correlated scalar subqueries must be Aggregated" mean?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 2.0.

I'd like to execute the following SQL query:

```
val sqlText = """
select
  f.ID as TID,
  f.BldgID as TBldgID,
  f.LeaseID as TLeaseID,
  f.Period as TPeriod,
  coalesce(
    (select
       f ChargeAmt
     from
       Fact_CMCharges f
     where
       f.BldgID = Fact_CMCharges.BldgID
     limit 1),
     0) as TChargeAmt1,
  f.ChargeAmt as TChargeAmt2,
  l.EFFDATE as TBreakDate
from
  Fact_CMCharges f
join
  CMRECC l on l.BLDGID = f.BldgID and l.LEASID = f.LeaseID and l.INCCAT = f.IncomeCat and date_format(l.EFFDATE,'D')<>1 and f.Period=EFFDateInt(l.EFFDATE) 
where
  f.ActualProjected = 'Lease'
except(
  select * from TT1 t2 left semi join Fact_CMCharges f2 on t2.TID=f2.ID) 
"""
val query = spark.sql(sqlText)
query.show()
```

It seems that the inner statement in `coalesce` gives the following error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Correlated scalar subqueries must be Aggregated: GlobalLimit 1\n+- LocalLimit 1\n
```

What's wrong with the query?

Comment: @Gotch 
what i have found that the concept
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933118/does-sparksql-support-subquery
the queries are not that trivial way  to perform. but  i have some times  put the queries  between 'queries.......queries'  it worked for me in some situation but did not get the concrete idea here

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to make sure that your sub-query by definition (and not by data) only returns a single row. Otherwise Spark Analyzer complains while parsing the SQL statement.

So when catalyst can't make 100% sure just by looking at the SQL statement (without looking at your data) that the sub-query only returns a single row, this exception is thrown.

If you are sure that your subquery only gives a single row you can use one of the following [aggregation standard functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$), so Spark Analyzer is happy:

- `first`
- `avg`
- `max`
- `min`

Comment: I think these function names have to be used in upper case (FIRST, AVG, etc.)

Comment: In SQL case doesn't matter, in python the need to be lower case https://gist.github.com/romeokienzler/bfebc1c84dd2846d5b36f1182608fb9e

Comment: Not always. Spark SQL can be configured for case sensitivity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946104/enable-case-sensitivity-for-spark-sql-globally