# Enable case sensitivity for spark.sql globally

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The option `spark.sql.caseSensitive` controls whether column names etc should be case sensitive or not. It can be set e.g. by

```
spark_session.sql('set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true')
```

and is `false` per default.

It does not seem to be possible to enable it globally in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` with

```
spark.sql.caseSensitive: True
```

though.
Is that intended or is there some other file to set sql options?

Also in the [source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/63f077fbe50b4094340e9915db41d7dbdba52975/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L183) it is stated that it is highly discouraged to enable this at all. What is the rationale behind that advice?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As it turns out setting

```
spark.sql.caseSensitive: True
```

in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` DOES work after all. It just has to be done in the configuration of the Spark driver as well, not the master or workers. Apparently I forgot that when I last tried.

Answer (score 14):

Yet another way for PySpark. Using a `SparkSession` object named `spark`:

```py
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.caseSensitive', True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true") in your Python code, which worked for me.