# Spark SQL - Case insensitive string comparison

Tags: apache-spark-sql

In Spark SQL, is there any way to make the string comparison case insensitive globally? i.e. when applying the filter for the columns I would like to avoid the "lcase" function calls.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946104/enable-case-sensitivity-for-spark-sql-globally

Comment: Thanks. The link was about column names. I would like to know about value comparison.