# Why does Spark Analyzer report "Correlated scalar subqueries must be Aggregated" in Case?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

A test that uses `spark-sql` is failing due to the following error:

> Correlated scalar subqueries must be Aggregated

The relevant part of the SQL query that is failing:

```
COALESCE(
    CASE WHEN ndc_code IN 
    (SELECT CODE FROM BOC_MED_METADATA WHERE CODE_TYPE = 'ndc')
      THEN '180'
    END,
    CASE WHEN hcpcs_code IN 
    (SELECT CODE FROM BOC_MED_METADATA WHERE CODE_TYPE = 'hcpcs')
      THEN '180'
    END,
    med_order_end_dttm,
    CASE WHEN days_supply IS NOT NULL
      THEN
        CASE
          WHEN discontinued AND (med_order_recorded_dttm BETWEEN medication_start AND start_plus)
            THEN med_order_recorded_dttm
          WHEN discontinued AND (med_order_recorded_dttm > start_plus)
            THEN start_plus
          WHEN NOT discontinued
            THEN start_plus
        END
    END,
    medication_start
  )
```

The first two `cases` in the `coalesce` are what I added and caused the test to fail. I believe it is because of how the subqueries will return multiple rows but I'm not sure how to get around that. Any help is appreciated. If it makes a difference, this `SQL` is only run in spark for the tests, it is actually run on a snowflake warehouse in production.

Comment: Does the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357613/getting-error-correlated-scalar-sub-queries-must-be-aggregated-global-limit-1 help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused to see the error as I don't see how the subqueries could've been considered correlated. What are they correlated on?

Anyway, to get rid of the error (which I think happens at analysis time which is before the query gets executed) is to use any standard aggregate function that assure Spark Analyzer that the queries do return just a single row with a single column or no row at all (that would give `null` as the result).

You could use `first` or `max` standard aggregate functions as follows:

```
SELECT first(CODE) FROM BOC_MED_METADATA WHERE CODE_TYPE = 'ndc'
```

I don't think Spark should report the exception since I can't find any correlated queries and using SQL `IN` should really accept any number of values from a subquery. I *am* confused.

Answer (score 0):

If this code:

```
CASE WHEN ndc_code IN 
              (SELECT CODE FROM BOC_MED_METADATA WHERE CODE_TYPE = 'ndc')
     THEN '180'
```

Is generating an error of the form

> Correlated scalar subqueries must be Aggregated

And the error message is accurate, then either `CODE` or `CODETYPE` is missing from the table.  So, my first recommendation is to qualify all column names:

```
CASE WHEN ndc_code IN 
              (SELECT bmm.CODE FROM BOC_MED_METADATA bmm WHERE bmm.CODE_TYPE = 'ndc')
     THEN '180'
```

This should return an error that one or the other columns are not found.

Comment: I qualified the columns and am still getting the same error. Here is what the stack trace looks like: `Filter (CODE#479 = outer(ndc_code#532))
+- SubqueryAlias boc_med_metadata
   +- Relation[id#478L,code#479,code_type#480,active_window#481] parquet`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `IN`, use `EXISTS` in the first two `CASE` statements.  Try this:

```
COALESCE(
    CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM BOC_MED_METADATA WHERE CODE_TYPE = 'ndc' AND CODE = ndc_code) 
      THEN '180'
    END,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM BOC_MED_METADATA WHERE CODE_TYPE = 'hcpcs' AND CODE = hcpcs_code)
      THEN '180'
    END,
    med_order_end_dttm,
    CASE WHEN days_supply IS NOT NULL
      THEN
        CASE
          WHEN discontinued AND (med_order_recorded_dttm BETWEEN medication_start AND start_plus)
            THEN med_order_recorded_dttm
          WHEN discontinued AND (med_order_recorded_dttm > start_plus)
            THEN start_plus
          WHEN NOT discontinued
            THEN start_plus
        END
    END,
    medication_start
  )
```

If the above fails, try qualifying `ndc_code` and `hcpcs_code` with the table name.