# Correlated scalar variable must be aggregated for a scalar sub-query in spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I have a `Dataset<Row>` which contains six columns in it, like below:

```
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |  time         | thingId       |     controller | module| variableName |  value |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |1554188264901  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Voltage       |    5   |
 |1554188264901  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    7   |
 |1554188276412  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Voltage       |    9   |
 |1554188276412  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    10  |  
 |1554188639406  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    6   |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
```

***End Goal:***

Getting the *last updated row* based on `MAX(time)`, for the combination of `thingId`, `controller`, `module` and `variableName`.

so the required output should have `MAX(time)` in all the rows, and last_updatedValue for rest of the variableName values.

```
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |  time         | thingId       |     controller | module| variableName |  value |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |1554188639406  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    6   |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
```

and the column `variableName` has two values (`'Voltage'` and `'SetPoint'`) for this particular thingId, controller and module so for the value `Voltage` in column `variableName` it should return *last updated row* for the value `Voltage` with `MAX(time)`.

like below, ***Expected Output:***

```
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |  time         | thingId       |     controller | module| variableName |  value |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |1554188276412  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Voltage       |    9   |
 |1554188639406  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    6   |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
```

***What I tried:***

I tried `Scalar sub-query` to get this, but the column inside sub-query should have been aggregated, I tried in multiple ways with no luck.

For example this code below:

```
 Dataset<Row> inputds = spark.read().format("avro").load("hdfs://path");
 inputds.createOrReplaceTempView("abc");
 Dataset<Row> update = spark.sql("select MAX(p.time) max_time, p.thingId, p.controller, p.module, p.variableName, (SELECT d.value from abc d where d.thingId=p.thingId and d.controller=p.controller and d.module=p.module and d.variableName=p.variableName group by thingId,controller,module,variableName,value) as values from abc p")
 update.show();
```

which throws the error:

> Correlated scalar variable must be aggregated for a scalar sub-query

How can I solve this? Please suggest me if there is any workaround.

Thank you!

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause at the end of your query.

Comment: @jarlh, Code in Question updated with `group by` and it throws `the output of correlated scalar sub-query must be aggregated`

Comment: Temporarily remove the sub-query. Does the query run? If not, add a GROUP BY.

Comment: @jarlh, it returns five columns as the expected output above except column `value`

Comment: what is the data type of `time` column?

Comment: @Johwhite, Long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it finally using `struct` in spark Dataset.

**Input Dataset**

```
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |  time         | thingId       |     controller | module| variableName |  value |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |1554188264901  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Voltage       |    5   |
 |1554188264901  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    7   |
 |1554188276412  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Voltage       |    9   |
 |1554188276412  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    10  |  
 |1554188639406  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    6   |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+

 Dataset<Row> intermediate = inputDS.groupby("thingId","controller","module","variableName").agg(max(struct("time","value")).as("time_value_struct")).select("thingId","controller","module","variableName","time_value_struct.*");

 //above code gives me intermediate output
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |  time         | thingId       |     controller | module| variableName |  value |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |1554188276412  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Voltage       |    9   |
 |1554188639406  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    6   |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
```

*So now my task is to take maximum value from `time` column and populate it for that thingId, controller and module for that used sql as below*

```
intermediate.createOrReplaceTempView("intermediate");

Dataset<Row> outputDS = spark.sql("select B.time,A.thingId,A.controller,A.module,A.variableName,A.value from intermediate A 
inner join (select thingId,controller,module,MAX(time)time from intermediate group by thingId,controller,module) B 
on A.thingId=B.thingId and A.controller=B.controller and A.module=B.module");
```

Which gives us **Expected output**

```
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |  time         | thingId       |     controller | module| variableName |  value |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |1554188639406  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Voltage       |    9   |
 |1554188639406  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    6   |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
```

So I can pivot now to get the last Updated value for every thingId, controller and module

I knew the `sql` for intermediate step has inner join in it, if I could able to figure out some efficient `sql` query instead of inner join that would be great.

Thank you @johwhite for the help

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you actually need both **aggregation** and **sorting**.

You need to have the value directly related to `MAX(time)`, *for that specific grouped value of the column* `variableName`, so basically the value which is on the same row. Since there is no aggregation function to do this in SQL, you could sort your sub-query results.

*So to achieve the desired* ***"last updated"*** *row,* you sort the sub-query by `time`, descending, and then you limit the results to just 1 row.

It may be something like this:

```
Dataset<Row> update = spark.sql("SELECT
    MAX(p.time) max_time,
    p.thingId, p.controller, p.module, p.variableName,
    (SELECT d.value FROM abc d WHERE d.thingId=p.thingId AND d.controller=p.controller AND d.module=p.module AND d.variableName=p.variableName
        ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1) AS [lastUpdatedValue]
FROM abc p
GROUP BY thingId,controller,module,variableName")
```

P.S. I come from a SQL Server Background, so to do that I would usually do `TOP 1`. I'm not entirely sure about `LIMIT 1` to have the same effects in Apache Spark SQL.

**EDIT:** I found [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$), thanks this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46271504/3283073).

Basically it's talking about an aggregation function in spark, called `first`.

Maybe using it in the sub-query is going to solve the issue?

```
    (SELECT first(d.value) FROM abc d WHERE d.thingId=p.thingId AND d.controller=p.controller AND d.module=p.module AND d.variableName=p.variableName
        ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1) AS [lastUpdatedValue]
```

Comment: I tried it throwing same error `correlated scalar sub-query must be aggregated`

Comment: [Here](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2728434780191932/1483312212640900/6987336228780374/latest.html) I found some more info, maybe something is going to help you. Check my last edit too!

Comment: same error `correlated scalar sub-query must be aggregated`, thanks for the link will try it now.!