# Spark SQL - How to filter rows based on lookup table

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, hiveql

I have first table with millions of rows with multiple columns, example:

```
ID   Name   Dept   City   State
11   sam    sales  Boston MA
22   Bob    market Atlanta GA
25   Mike   IT     SF     CA
```

and 2nd lookup table contains two rows with Number and States, example is as follows,

```
No State
1  CA
2  TX
```

How can I get results from first table excluding rows with state value present in table 2?
**Spark does not support subqueries, How this can be done in spark?**

Comment: Also Spark [supports subqueries since 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33933118/8371915).

Comment: i am using spark 1.6

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE state NOT IN (SELECT state FROM table2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is generic SQL, you can tweak it to your specific database.

On a separate note, if you have millions of records, make sure that the fields you are filtering on have indexes on them.

let me know if this helps.

```
select * from firsttable
where State not in (select distinct state from secondtable)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this  :

```
 SELECT *
  FROM   Table1
   LEFT JOIN Table2     
   ON     (Table1.state =      Table2.state)
   WHERE  Table2.state        IS NULL
```