# Perform a Correlated Scalar SubQuery in Spark Dataframe Java API (spark v2.3.0)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have read that in spark you can easily do a correlated scalar subquery like so:

```
select
    column1,
    (select column2 from table2 where table2.some_key = table1.id)
from table1
```

What I have not figured out is how to do this in the DataFrame API. The best I can come up with is to do a join. The problem with this is that in my specific case I am joining with a enum-like lookup table that actually applies to more than one column.

Below is an example of the DataFrame code.

```
Dataset<Row> table1 = getTable1FromSomewhere();
Dataset<Row> table2 = getTable2FromSomewhere();

table1
    .as("table1")
    .join(table2.as("table2"), 
            col("table1.first_key").equalTo(col("table2.key")), "left")
    .join(table2.as("table3"), 
            col("table1.second_key").equalTo(col("table3.key")), "left")
    .select(col("table1.*"), 
            col("table2.description").as("first_key_description"),
            col("table3.description").as("second_key_description"))
    .show();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated on figuring out how to do this in the DataFrame API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I have not figured out is how to do this in the DataFrame API.

Because there is simply no `DataFrame` API that can express that directly (without explicit `JOIN`). It can possibly change in the future:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23945
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18455
- [Does SparkSQL support subquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33933118)

Comment: That is super helpful. Thank you!  Given this restriction, is there a better/more elegant way to express what I am trying to do using the DataFrame join?