# spark SQL scala DSL subquery support

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

[Does SparkSQL support subquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933118/does-sparksql-support-subquery/33946024) lists that currently no subquery support is available for spark 2.0.

Has this changed recently?

Comment: https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2728434780191932/1483312212640900/6987336228780374/latest.html outlines that subqueries are anyway translated to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. So not using a subquery in the first place (but a join) should not result in any performance penalty. EDIT: assumption is a correlated/ dependent subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment is correct. Your question is a little vague. However, I take your point and find also the concepts fine and also subject to this sort of question, so there you go.

So, this is now possible for the DataFrame API, not DataSet or DSL as you state.

```
 SELECT A.dep_id,
        A.employee_id,
        A.age,
       (SELECT  MAX(age) 
          FROM employee B 
         WHERE A.dep_id = B.dep_id) max_age
 FROM     employee A
 ORDER BY 1,2
```

An example - borrowed from the Internet, shows clearly the distinction between DS and DF implying that a SPARK SQL correlated sub-query (not shown here of course) does also not happen against a DataSet - by deduction:

```
sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM src").show()
val sqlDF = sql("SELECT key, value FROM src WHERE key < 10 ORDER BY key") 
val stringsDS = sqlDF.map {case Row(key: Int, value: String) => s"Key: $key, Value: $value"}
stringsDS.show()
```

The SQL runs against some source like Hive or Parquet or against SPARK TempViews, not against a DS. From a DF you can go to the DS and then enjoy the more typesafe approach, but only with the limited interface on select. I did a good search to find something that disproves this, but this is not the case. DS and DF are sort of interchangeable anyway as I have stated I think to you earlier. But, I see you are very thorough!

Moreover, there are at least 2 techniques for converting the Nested-Correlated=Subqueries to "normal" JOINs which is what SPARK and indeed other Optimizers do in the background. E.g. RewriteCorrelatedScalarSubquery and PullupCorrelatedPredicate.

But for a DSL, which you allude to, you can re-write your query by hand to achieve the same, by using JOIN, LEFT JOIN, OUTER JOIN, whatever the case may be. Except that is not so obvious for all oddly enough.

Comment: But this is simply the text based sql query. Not using scala dsl

Comment: Spark offers (even for untyped DataFrame API) a scala DSL (which is a bit more compiler aware / type safe) https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#untyped-dataset-operations-aka-dataframe-operations and as you demonstrated the text based SQL API. I wonder of subqueries are also constructible in the scala DSL API or if as already commented above as they are anyways translated to a LEFT JOIN  one simply should join them manually.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: that is still only using the textual API.

Comment: That is the way it works, Georg. I will be gladly correcred.

Comment: What you outline is the answer for uncorrelated sub queries. I am interested in correlated subqueries But have realized meanwhile that manually doing a left join of two datasets achieves the same thing. See the initial comment. You can use that as your answer an then I can accept it. I would also be really interested in learning what catalyst will do in such a case with the filtered dataframe when caching is enabled. I somehow can only get it to cache one and not both I.e. Full and filtered dataframe.

Comment: But they are not possible for DSL, yet. There are at least 2 ways to optimize sub queries that are nested and correlated. Interestingly most people tend to think nested correlated. The spark doc is lacking on Catalyst. I am running my own queries to see how good with a nested correlated subquey on tempviews.

Comment: I think my answer is hood enough bug will look later tonight.

Comment: good not hood. I will check on databricks. I was getting cached with persist working OK on random generated data, which I needed to persist. But I will get back to you to confirm, that may be the second one was not the case - just in case!

Comment: Updated answer.