# Unable to execute nested SQL queries in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to execute this query but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT COLUMN
FROM TABLE A           
WHERE  A.COLUM_1 = '9999-12-31' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 ET WHERE ET.COl1 = A.COL2 LIMIT 1)
```

It results in an error which says the following:

> "mismatched input FROM expecting"

[Went through this post as it states its supported by Spark with 2.0+ version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933118/does-sparksql-support-subquery).

Comment: **AND** NOT EXISTS?

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: version - 2.3.0

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that SparkSQL supports `TOP`.  But it is not needed.  Does this work?

```
SELECT t.COLUMN
FROM TABLE t           
WHERE t.COLUM_1 = '9999-12-31' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 ET WHERE ET.COl1 = t.COL2);
```

This fixes a few other syntax issues with the query (such as no alias `A`).

`LIMIT` in the subquery is also not needed.  `NOT EXISTS` should stop at the first match.

Comment: Yes iam sorry TOP is incorrect as its not supported, i should be using `LIMIT 1` i suppose instead of `TOP 1`, Thanks BTW