# mismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF> SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I am running a process on Spark which uses SQL for the most part. In one of the workflows I am getting the following error:

> mismatched input 'from' expecting

The code is

```
 select a.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER,a.LAN_CD, a.BEST_CARD_NUMBER,  
 decision_id, 
 case when a.BEST_CARD_NUMBER = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end as best_card_excl_flag 
 from (select a.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER,a.LAN_CD, a. decision_id row_number()
 over (partition by CUST_GRP_MBRP_ID 
    order by coalesce(BEST_CARD_RANK,999)) as BEST_CARD_NUMBER 
 from Accounts_Inclusions_Exclusions_Flagged a) a
```

I cannot figure out what the error is for the life of me

I've tried checking for comma errors or unexpected brackets but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Is it just the missing comma before `row_number()`?

Comment: I get a different error when I drop your query into SQL Fiddle: "Incorrect syntax near '('." http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9bfef/3

Comment: Pretty sure SparkSQL no longer allows inner queries https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933118/does-sparksql-support-subquery

Comment: Please improve your code formatting. It is hard to read. Use correct upper case letters, indention and line breaks for example. Also improve your title with correct upper case letters.

Answer (score 7):

In the 4th line of you code, you just need to add a comma after a.decision_id, since row_number() over is a separate column/function.

P.S.: Try yo use indentation in nested select statements so you and your peers can understand the code easily. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is in the inner query.  You have a space between `a.` and `decision_id` and you are missing a comma between `decision_id` and `row_number()`.

Is this what you want?

```
 SELECT
    a.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER,
    a.LAN_CD,
    a.BEST_CARD_NUMBER,
    decision_id, 
    CASE WHEN a.BEST_CARD_NUMBER = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS best_card_excl_flag 
 FROM (
    SELECT
        a.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER,
        a.LAN_CD,
        a.decision_id,
        row_number() OVER (partition BY CUST_GRP_MBRP_ID ORDER BY COALESCE(BEST_CARD_RANK,999)) AS BEST_CARD_NUMBER 
    FROM Accounts_Inclusions_Exclusions_Flagged A
 ) A;
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to say this is just a syntax error. I think it is occurring at the end of the original query at the last FROM statement. Of course, I could be wrong.

Try the following:

```
'SELECT a.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER, a.LAN_CD, a.BEST_CARD_NUMBER, decision_id,
    CASE    
        WHEN a.BEST_CARD_NUMBER = 1 THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS best_card_excl_flag
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CUST_GRP_MBRP
                                ORDER BY COALESCE(BEST_CARD_RANK, 999)) AS 
BEST_CARD_NUMBER,
            a.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER, a.LAN_CD, a.decision_id
    FROM Accounts_Inclusions_Exclusions_Flagged) AS a;'
```

I hope this helps some.

Answer (score -1):

FROM should not be in the last sentence.